# <h1> styling not working but others will

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using django and my `<p>` selector is working but the `<h1>` is not.

I cant understand why some css is working and others isnt.

What order does bootstrap work in?

It does find the style.css file my text of the

element works

```
    style.css

font-family: 'Wendy One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Baloo', cursive;
font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;


h1 {
    color:yellow;
    font-family: "Baloo", cursive;
}

p  {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<h1 class="text-center" >The Wish Fairy Foundation</h1>
<p> this should be the index of wishfairies.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">




{% block title %}{% endblock %}




<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Libre+Baskerville|Wendy+One" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

</head>



{% block header %}


{% endblock %}

<body>

{% block sidebar %}



{% endblock %}


<div class="container">

{% block content %} 

{% endblock %}
</div>

{% block footer %}



{% endblock %}

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use "!important" in your custom css,  for e.g h1 {
    color:yellow !important ;
    font-family: "Baloo", cursive !important;
}

Comment: It would be better if you include here how you call your fonts and stylesheets

Comment: Are any of the `h1` styles working, like the color? Or is it all not working?

Comment: nothing in the <h1> works

Comment: When you inspect the `h1` in the browser, does it show any of those styles, are they being overridden by other styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style.css file is invalid. The `font-family` lines aren't enclosed in any selectors, so they're breaking the next rule (`h1`)

Wrap the font-family lines in something. I'm assuming you want to wrap them in individual elements so that they don't overwrite one another.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style>
.wendy {
  font-family: 'Wendy One', sans-serif;
}

.baloo {
  font-family: 'Baloo', cursive;
}

.libre {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}

h1 {
    color:yellow;
    font-family: "Baloo", cursive;
}

p  {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
</style>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Libre+Baskerville|Wendy+One" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>h1</h1>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Comment: @ michael How you do this?we were blind.. #fan:)